# statistics with "group by" or "uniq"

Tags: python, mysql, perl, shell

I have the following "basefile.csv"

```
AAM7676,2012-02-02 11:55:52,32,2012-02-03 19:55:30,62,1
AAM7676,2012-02-11 13:56:11,32,2012-02-12 21:00:18,52,2
AAM7676,2012-02-21 16:30:55,32,2012-02-23 13:29:41,62,1
AAM7676,2012-03-07 20:03:32,32,2012-03-09 13:31:35,62,1
AAM7676,2012-05-28 06:08:05,32,2012-05-29 15:49:55,52,2
AAM7676,2012-08-22 12:47:28,32,2012-08-24 08:03:09,52,1
AAO9229,2012-01-10 07:19:29,32,2012-01-11 16:39:16,52,2
AAP0678,2012-04-09 16:35:19,32,2012-04-10 19:46:55,52,2
AAP0678,2012-04-30 16:44:28,32,2012-05-01 19:20:00,52,2
AAP0678,2012-06-01 19:31:34,32,2012-06-03 10:34:33,52,3
AAU6100,2012-01-09 17:49:13,32,2012-01-11 02:00:33,52,3
AAU6100,2012-01-20 21:18:16,32,2012-01-22 14:09:00,52,3
AAU6100,2012-02-20 13:35:39,32,2012-02-21 19:45:55,52,2
AAU6100,2012-03-13 09:50:51,32,2012-03-14 22:35:51,52,3
```

Based on column 1 (car plate) and column 4 (date-time), I'd like to make statistics to show how many times per month (column 4) a plate (column 1) occurs.

Final format, should be:

```
plate,jan,feb,mar,abr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep.oct,nov,dec,total
AAM7676,0,3,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,6
AAO9229,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
AAP0678,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3
AAU6100,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4
```

I have already played with (and searched for solutions) shell script and MySQL without figuring out how to solve it... probably because I'm a newbie....

Any kind of solution will be welcomed (MySQL, sh, perl, python, ...)

Comment: Are the lines in the csv sorted by plate and by date? Your example seems to indicate so.

Comment: Do you have to worry about the fields ever being enclosed in quotes and containing commas?  There's no obvious reason why any of them would, but if there's a danger, you need proper CSV-aware software rather than the majority of Unix tools.

Comment: yes, the fields are already sorted by columns $1, $4.

Comment: in fact I never minded about putting the field enclosed in quotes, since there's no comas, others than the fields separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically a poster-child kind of question for [Python Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). I assume column header names: license, time1, num1, time2, num2, count (in that order).

```
import pandas, numpy as np
df = pandas.io.parsers.read_csv("baseline.csv")
df["month"] = df["time2"].map(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1]))
df.groupby(["license","month"]).apply(len)
```

which outputs:

```
license  month
AAM7676  2        3
         3        1
         5        1
         8        1
AAO9229  1        1
AAP0678  4        1
         5        1
         6        1
AAU6100  1        2
         2        1
         3        1
```

Then you have a multi-indexed Pandas Series of your counts, so you can format the output table however you want. However, it's not too hard to format to print something very much like what you want straight from Pandas:

```
t = df.groupby(["license","month"]).apply(len)
t.unstack(level=0).reindex(index=range(1,13), fill_value=0).T.fillna(0)
```

prints out:

```
               1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
      license
count AAM7676   0   3   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
      AAO9229   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
      AAP0678   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
      AAU6100   2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

While this solution requires (a) header names and (b) two third-party libraries; it comes with huge wins. You can aggregate and apply grouped operations very easily and they are optimized just like NumPy. And this will work well for very large data or for computing many different secondary stats with your data, if needed.

Let me be clear because I usually get shot down for answers like this. Knowing how to do this with pure Python is a great thing to know and Python programmers should take the time to learn it. However, don't re-invent wheels just for the sake of Python. Pandas offers some awesome tools for exactly this kind of data manipulation.

Comment: The solution is really great !!! I'm starting learning python, and didn't know Panda. It's a very powerful library !! Thanks for the answer !!

Comment: No problem. If you're new to python, definitely study the other answers too. You want to feel comfortable doing things like this in pure python before relying too much on extra libraries. But indeed Pandas is quickly becoming the standard for stuff like this.

Comment: Also, you can click the check mark next to any of the answers to 'accept' it as the answer if it was helpful for you. As you build up karma points, it will also display the percentage of answers you have accepted. The higher this is, the more likely someone is to help later, because they will believe that you'll award points if they help you.

Answer (score 3):

The following Python solution should work:

```
import csv
import collections

result = collections.OrderedDict()
for cols in csv.reader(open('basefile.csv')):
    if len(cols) != 6:
        continue
    plate = cols[0]
    month = int(cols[3][5:7])
    result.setdefault(plate, [plate] + [0]*12)[month] += 1

print 'plate,jan,feb,mar,abr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep.oct,nov,dec,total'
for row in result.values():
    print ','.join(map(str, row)) + ',' + str(sum(row[1:]))
```

Comment: Also, if the input is sorted on plate and dates, you can use `itertools.groupby` (nested twice) to help count.

Comment: in fact there are 6 columns (plate, date-1, id-1, date-2, id-2, ref)

Answer (score 3):

Using gawk:

```
gawk -F, '
    {
        plate[$1]++
        split($4, dt, /-0*/)
        count[$1,dt[2]]++
    }
    END {
        print "plate,jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec,total"
        n = asorti(plate, ordered_plates)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            p = ordered_plates[i]
            printf("%s,", p)
            for (m=1; m<=12; m++) 
                printf("%d,", count[p,m])
            print plate[p]
        }
    }
' basefile.csv
```

outputs

```
plate,jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec,total
AAM7676,0,3,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,6
AAO9229,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
AAP0678,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3
AAU6100,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4
```

Comment: Worded like a charm !!! Those unix command lines tools are really great. Thanks you !!

Answer (score 3):

A Perl solution. It assumes there are no embedded commas in any of the fields.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/ sum /;

my %data;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($plate, $col4) = (split /,/)[0, 3];
    my ($month) = $col4 =~ /-(\d\d)-/;
    $data{$plate}{$month}++;
}

print join(",", qw/ plate jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec total /), "\n";

for my $plate (sort keys %data) {
    my @per_month = map $data{$plate}{$_} || 0, '01' .. '12';
    print join(",", $plate, @per_month, sum @per_month), "\n";
}

__DATA__
AAM7676,2012-02-02 11:55:52,32,2012-02-03 19:55:30,62,1 
AAM7676,2012-02-11 13:56:11,32,2012-02-12 21:00:18,52,2 
AAM7676,2012-02-21 16:30:55,32,2012-02-23 13:29:41,62,1 
AAM7676,2012-03-07 20:03:32,32,2012-03-09 13:31:35,62,1 
AAM7676,2012-05-28 06:08:05,32,2012-05-29 15:49:55,52,2 
AAM7676,2012-08-22 12:47:28,32,2012-08-24 08:03:09,52,1 
AAO9229,2012-01-10 07:19:29,32,2012-01-11 16:39:16,52,2 
AAP0678,2012-04-09 16:35:19,32,2012-04-10 19:46:55,52,2 
AAP0678,2012-04-30 16:44:28,32,2012-05-01 19:20:00,52,2 
AAP0678,2012-06-01 19:31:34,32,2012-06-03 10:34:33,52,3 
AAU6100,2012-01-09 17:49:13,32,2012-01-11 02:00:33,52,3 
AAU6100,2012-01-20 21:18:16,32,2012-01-22 14:09:00,52,3 
AAU6100,2012-02-20 13:35:39,32,2012-02-21 19:45:55,52,2 
AAU6100,2012-03-13 09:50:51,32,2012-03-14 22:35:51,52,3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep a dictionary of lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda : [None]+[0]*12)

with open('yourfile') as f:
    for line in f:
        plate,_,_,time,_,_ = line.split(',')  #maybe use csv instead
        month = int(time.split('-')[1])       #get the month
        d[plate][month] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Stage 1: Generate entries with plate and year/month

```
cut -d, -f1,4 basefile.csv |
sed 's/,2012-\([0-9][0-9]\)-[0-9][0-9] ..:..:..$/ \1/'
```

This assumes that the dates are all 2012, and also maps the comma separator to a space.

Example output:

```
AAM7676 02
AAM7676 02
AAM7676 02
AAM7676 03
AAM7676 05
AAM7676 08
AAO9229 01
AAP0678 04
AAP0678 05
AAP0678 06
AAU6100 01
AAU6100 01
AAU6100 02
AAU6100 03
```

#### Stage 2: Generate counts per month

```
... |
sort | uniq -c
```

Sample output:

```
3 AAM7676 02
1 AAM7676 03
1 AAM7676 05
1 AAM7676 08
1 AAO9229 01
1 AAP0678 04
1 AAP0678 05
1 AAP0678 06
2 AAU6100 01
1 AAU6100 02
1 AAU6100 03
```

#### Stage 3: Pivot

The data is in order of plate and month.  At this point, I'd use `awk` to create a control-break report:

```
cut -d, -f1,4 basefile.csv |
sed 's/,2012-\([0-9][0-9]\)-[0-9][0-9] ..:..:..$/ \1/' |
sort |
uniq -c |
awk '
    {   if ($2 != last_plate && last_plate != "")
        {
            printf "%s", last_plate
            for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                printf ",%d", count[i]
                count[i] = 0;
            }
            print ""
        }
        last_plate = $2
        count[$3+0] = $1
    }
    END {   if (last_plate != "")
            {
                printf "%s", last_plate
                for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
                    printf ",%d", count[i]
                print ""
            }
    }'
```

The only 'trick' in there is the subscript `count[$3+0]`; this converts the strings such as `01` into a pure number 1 for the subscript.

The output on the sample data is:

```
AAM7676,0,3,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
AAO9229,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
AAP0678,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
AAU6100,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

If you want the column headers too, that's a trivial addition of a BEGIN block and appropriate `print` statement in the `awk` script.

Could it all be done in `awk`?  Probably...be my guest.  The sort is the only tricky bit.  It could also all be done in Perl or Python or other similar scripting languages.

Answer (score 1):

Although 12 columns for monthes isn't exactly natural in RBDS,
the following SQL COUNT and GROUP BY do the trick :

```
drop table if exists toto;
create table toto(
    plate VARCHAR(32),
    date1 DATETIME,
    something1 INT(10),
    date2 DATETIME,
    something2 INT(10),
    something3 INT(10)
);

INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAM7676','2012-02-02 11:55:52',32,'2012-02-03 19:55:30',62,1);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAM7676','2012-02-11 13:56:11',32,'2012-02-12 21:00:18',52,2);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAM7676','2012-02-21 16:30:55',32,'2012-02-23 13:29:41',62,1);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAM7676','2012-03-07 20:03:32',32,'2012-03-09 13:31:35',62,1);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAM7676','2012-05-28 06:08:05',32,'2012-05-29 15:49:55',52,2);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAM7676','2012-08-22 12:47:28',32,'2012-08-24 08:03:09',52,1);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAO9229','2012-01-10 07:19:29',32,'2012-01-11 16:39:16',52,2);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAP0678','2012-04-09 16:35:19',32,'2012-04-10 19:46:55',52,2);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAP0678','2012-04-30 16:44:28',32,'2012-05-01 19:20:00',52,2);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAP0678','2012-06-01 19:31:34',32,'2012-06-03 10:34:33',52,3);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAU6100','2012-01-09 17:49:13',32,'2012-01-11 02:00:33',52,3);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAU6100','2012-01-20 21:18:16',32,'2012-01-22 14:09:00',52,3);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAU6100','2012-02-20 13:35:39',32,'2012-02-21 19:45:55',52,2);
INSERT INTO toto VALUES('AAU6100','2012-03-13 09:50:51',32,'2012-03-14 22:35:51',52,3);


SELECT 
    t.plate,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=1),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=2),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=3),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=4),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=5),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=6),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=7),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=8),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=9),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=10),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=11),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toto tt WHERE tt.plate=t.plate AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date1)=12),
    COUNT(*)
FROM toto t
GROUP BY plate;
```

Result :

```
AAM7676 0   3   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   6
AAO9229 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
AAP0678 0   0   0   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   3
AAU6100 2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  plate,
  COUNT(IF(MONTH(dt2) = 1, 1, NULL)) jan,
  COUNT(IF(MONTH(dt2) = 2, 1, NULL)) feb,
  COUNT(IF(MONTH(dt2) = 3, 1, NULL)) mar,
  COUNT(IF(MONTH(dt2) = 4, 1, NULL)) apr,
  COUNT(IF(MONTH(dt2) = 5, 1, NULL)) may,
  COUNT(*) total
FROM
  basefile_table
WHERE
  YEAR(dt2) = 2012
GROUP BY
  plate;

+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| plate   | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | total |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| AAM7676 |   0 |   3 |   1 |   0 |   1 |     6 |
| AAO9229 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |     1 |
| AAP0678 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |     3 |
| AAU6100 |   2 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |     4 |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Add other months - june, july,...
Note I have added year filter to the query.

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thanks for the answer. I'll have to learn a little more on "count" and "group by".